# Why I'm getting duplicate push notifications on iOS 9?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am receiving the same push notification twice in iOS 9, but It is working fine in iOS 8.

The problem still persists after updating the iOS version to 9.1, 9.2.
The application is generating new device tokens every time the app gets uninstalled and re-installed.

I found a solution which suggested to keep the latest device token id tagged with the user and remove all the previously tagged device token's, but I want my user to log in to the app from multiple devices (like an iPad & an iPhone) so I can't follow the solution.

Any possible solution/tips to handle this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use keychain to store or update device tokens. It can't be removed when application is uninstalled.

Comment: How it will help me to use the same app on different devices with same user  details?

Comment: ex:
front side:
in iphone, application will store iphone's device tokens. 
in ipad, it will store ipad's device tokens.

server side:
user A you store 2 record
iphone: user_id and iphone's device_token
ipad: user_id and ipad's device_token

when you update new device token. in your API parameter , you should pass old device token. If old device token = null => it mean new install => add new device token, otherwise you update new device token

Comment: I already multiple installs of my app done, so using this procedure may restrict some of the current users with "nil" value to get the app notifications,  & what to do if user restricts the use of keychain for the app in this device??